# How to run add absolute path to custom python module/library at Pyscript on web server

Tags: python, python-module, pyscript, pyscripter

I need to run my code from custom library and show it at clientside/browser
I have problem with run code Pyscript from custom library when i`m include path (by recommendation https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/519) at my hosting web side for client

```
https://test.com/lib/python/example/index.html with code 👇
```

```
<html>
<head>
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2022.12.1/pyscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2022.12.1/pyscript.css"/>
</head>
<body>    

<py-config>
    [[fetch]] 
paths = ["https://test.com/lib/python/example/custom/example.py"] #custom py-module
or 
[[fetch]]
url = "https://test.com/lib/python/example/"
folder = "custom/"
files = ["example.py"]
or
[[fetch]]
path = "lib/python/example/custom/example.py"
uri = "https://test.com/lib/python/example/custom/example.py"

# example.py
/* code file
def hello():
    print("Pyscript")
*/

</py-config>

<py-script>
    import example
    example.hello()
</py-script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Paths on server:

```
with path
|---https://test.com/lib/python/example/custom/
|---------------------------------------------/index.html
|---------------------------------------------/example.py

or
|---https://test.com/lib/python/example/custom/
|---------------------------------------------/index.html
|---------------------------------------------/py/example.py
```

I have error - (PY1000): Couldn't determine the filename from the path , please supply 'to_file' parameter.

How can i resolve it and run my custom module code by absolutely path to Pyscript on web hosting and show it  ?

Comment: First, the issue you cite is more than a year old. It is always best to consult the latest about pyscript as it develops at a fairly fast pace. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75376605/8508004) and [here](https://jeff.glass/post/pyscript-need-a-server/) are more pertinent than that link. That former link actual references particular places in the pyscript documentation, plus see https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html#local-modules just above there. If you want to get actual specifics on help, I'd suggest creating a toy Github spaces-enabled ...

Comment: <continued> repository with some content and try there and then share that and what you've tried. https://test.com/lib/python/example/index.html doesn't work. Plus, I'm not sure why you are referring to absolute path. You probably don't need the absolute path if you put it alongside your page code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<py-config>
  [[fetch]]
  files = ['example.py'] #name of your py-file
  from = '../lib/python/example/custom/py/' #folder where placed your py-file
</py-config>
<py-script>
  import example
  example.hello()
</py-script>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong attributes for [`<py-config>`](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html#local-modules). The attribute you want is `files`, which takes a list of (relative or absolute URLs:

```html
<py-config>
  [[fetch]]
  files = ['example.py']
</py-config>
<py-script>
  import example
  example.hello()
</py-script>
```

By default, all loaded files are placed in the same directory that Python code is executed from. If you want to place it in a different folder in the emscripten virtual file system, use the `to_folder` attribute. To specify a specific file name to store the content at (e.g. if you're loading content from a URL that doesn't end in `[filename].py`), use `to_file`.